# mactex-basic and authordate1 style

Tags: bibtex, installing, mactex

Need some help.. I installed the light version of MacTeX (BasicTeX), and found out that it doesn't contain the 'authordate1' bibtex style that I need.

I downloaded that style on CTAN in a ZIP file containing the following files:

```
README
authordate1.ltx
authordate3.bst
authordate4.ltx
authordate1-4.sty
authordate2.bst
authordate3.ltx
testadb.ltx
authordate1.bst
authordate2.ltx
authordate4.bst
```

How do I install it (using `tlmgr`?) ?

Thanks in advance!
Jonathan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run

```
tlmgr search --global --file authordate1.bst
```

the shell will output

```
tlmgr: package repository http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet
beebe:
    texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/beebe/authordate1.bst
```

(the repository name may be different, of course). Thus you know that the relevant package is called `beebe`; indeed, running

```
tlmgr info beebe --list
```

outputs the package's contents, where the files you're looking for are listed.

Therefore you need

```
tlmgr install beebe
```

Answer (score 0):

BasicTeX is worth its name: it is basic, the strict minimum, so such files as these are certainly not to be found in it.

It seems moreover that they are not available in CTAN repositories for TeXLive (TeX Live Utility, MacTeX's graphical interface to tlmgr, doesn't mention them).

The easiest way to install them is to create your own `texmf`folder in your personal Library, and therein also create `bibtex/bst` and `tex/latex` folders, that is to say following the paths

`/Users/your_name/Library/texmf/bibtex/bst`

and

`/Users/your_name/Library/texmf/tex/latex`.

In each of these folders, create an `authordate` folder. In

`/Users/your_name/Library/texmf/bibtex/bst/authordate`

put your `.bst` files, and in

`/Users/your_name/Library/texmf/tex/latex/authordate`

put your `.ltx` files.

Then LaTeX and BibTeX should recognize them.

Edit: Or better, follow egreg's instructions! :-)